# ClickOnce WPF Application Randomly can't download updates and won't start (unable to reproduce errors on demand)

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I have a WPF Clickonce application that is installed locally but accesses an ftp path to check for updates.

I publish the application to my server, then I copy all the files in that published out folder to my local computer. Then I run the .application file. The application installs locally and I can run it perfectly fine.

Then after a day or so I get the error: "Application download did not succeed. Check your network connection, or contact your system administrator or network service provider."

In the logs I'm getting "The Network Name cannot be found."

I figured okay this is a DNS error. But in the command prompt I can ping that server by name.

And when I uninstall the application, and reinstall it - it works again.

Before reinstalling, I've also tried clearing the cache by deleting everything in the folder: %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ but still no luck.

Anyone know what's going on?

It's just impractical to have to reinstall everything couple days